# Laplace transform of $\cos(at)/t$

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, laplace-method

If someone could help me solve for $$\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{\cos(at)}{t}\right\}$$ it would be great.

Step-by-step I have so far:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(at)\space e^{-st}}{t}\space\text{d}s &= \int_s^\infty \frac{s}{s^2+a^2}\space\text{d}s \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \int_s^\infty \frac{2s}{s^2+a^2}\space\text{d}s \\  \end{align}$$
Help me after this step please

Comment: This "as soon as possible" usually does not fare well on this site, Sumukh.So as Graydad suggested, share your thoughts with us about how you tried to solve this problem

Comment: First time ever using this forum. Sorry about that @graydad @ imranfat

Comment: @graydad Oh. My bad. Can you please tell me how to solve this problem? And edit the question details as u see fit. The question is L{1/t * cos(at)}

Comment: @graydad from 2nd step, it is 's to infinity' not '0 to infinity'

Integral of s to infinity of s/(s^2 + a^2) ds

In the last one it is 1/2 * ln(s^2 + a^2) as it goes from s to infinity.

Comment: edited @graydad thanks for sparing your time for to help me man. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @graydad I might me be wrong from the beginning. Please show me how to solve it from first.

Comment: I asked my professor about this. He said that it was an typing error in the problem set. Sorry for the confusion I might have caused

Comment: so you meant $\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{\cos(at)}{t}1_{t > 0}\right\}$

Comment: @user1952009 In the problem set, it said find laplace transform of (cos(at))/t  As explained by another user below in the answers, it does not converge. It was a typing error in the problem set. Sorry for the confusion I might have caused

Comment: @penouch : that the integral diverses doesn't mean the Laplace transform doesn't exists (in the sense of distributions). and $\displaystyle\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{\cos(at)}{t}1_{t > b}\right\}$ exists for any $b > 0$ (and even $b < 0$), as well as $\displaystyle\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{\cos(at)}{t^{1-\epsilon}}1_{t > 0}\right\}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding something, but the integral should be in $t$, right? Ordinarily, if we have a function $f(t)$, the Laplace transform is $$(\mathcal Lf)(s) = \int^\infty_0 f(t) e^{-st} dt.$$ Here, because of the behavior near $t =0$, we see that the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(at)}{t} e^{-st} dt$$ doesn't converge. Indeed, for small $\varepsilon  > 0$, we see by Taylor expansion that $$\int^\varepsilon_0 \frac{\cos(at)}{t} e^{-st} dt \approx \int^\varepsilon_0 \frac 1 t dt$$ which diverges.

Comment: I asked my professor about this. He said that it was an typing error in the problem set. Sorry for the confusion I might have caused @User8128

Comment: @penouch : so what ? the question can be answered anyway

Comment: @user1952009 how? I wrote that the series diverges and hence laplace transform for the given expression does not exist. Is there an other way?

Comment: Can you check my answer and point out the mistake please ?

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with a fresh approach.

Here is a property of Laplace Transforms I'd like to use :

$$\begin{align} 
&&f(t) = L^{-1} F(s)\\ 
\implies&& tf(t) = L^{-1} -\frac{d}{ds} F(s) \\ 
\end{align}$$

So let's begin. Let $F(t)$ satisfy this equation. 
$$\begin{align}
F(t) &&= L^{-1} \log(s^2 + a^2)\\ 
\implies tF(t) &&= L^{-1}-\frac{d}{ds}log(s^2 + a^2)\\
\implies tF(t) &&= L^{-1}-\frac{2s}{s^2 +a^2}\\
\implies tF(t) &&= -2\cos(at) \\ 
\implies F(t) &&= -2\frac{\cos(at)}{t}\\
\implies \frac{\cos(at)}{t} &&= \frac{F(t)}{-2}\\
\implies L\frac{\cos(at)}{t} &&= L(\frac{F(t)}{-2})\\ 
\implies L\frac{\cos(at)}{t} &&= \frac{\log|s^2 + a^2|}{-2})\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: I feel there is something wrong here but not sure what. The reason is that I am unable to find a way to reach this answer from the integral where OP reached.

Comment: I asked my professor about this. He said that it was an typing error in the problem set. Sorry for the confusion I might have caused @user230452

Comment: @user230452 : you forgot the integration constants

Comment: @penouch That is fine but I'd still like to know the answer to this question.

Comment: @user1952009 but, I didn't perform integration anywhere!

Comment: @user230452 what about line 2 $\to$ 3 ? and you should replace $L^{-1}$ by $FT^{-1}$

Comment: @user1952009 Actually, it's not clear. But lines 1 and 2 were stating the property I was using. My approach starts from line 3. By FT, do you mean Fourier Transform?